# Copying all JIRA issues into a Database

Tags: sql-server, database, jira, data-warehouse

I have a clean Database setup with the intention of placing all the JIRA issues for my company into it. Before doing some further actions as Proofs of Concept.

My problem is that i (am incompetent) do not have access to the JIRA database directly, i.e. i cannot change the config to just connect straight to JIRA which is what i had initially hoped.

Is there a relatively fast way of getting all of the issues from JIRA (as a standard user who has access to them) and them placing them into a sql-server 2012 database?

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct would be to use the [JIRA API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues) with some programming to pull all issues for certain JIRA projects and add only relevant information to your database.

You will have to setup your database tables before hand and know which data fields to keep.